# How long would it take to integrate Facebook Connect with a website?

Tags: facebook

I have a website where users can buy deals posted by the site owner/admin and I would like to integrate Facebook Connect with it.  Can you please answer the following:

- **What tasks are involved with integrating Facebook Connect?**
- **How difficult would it be for a programmer to integrate Facebook Connect?**
- **How long would it take for an average programmer to integrate Facebook Connect?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple good tutorials available.  I would say an average programmer (with some familiarity in JavaScript) would be able to do this fairly easily.

- [Facebook Connect Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Facebook_Connect)
- [How to quickly add Facebook Connect](http://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=630563174283)

I have integrated Facebook Connect into 2 sites and the time it took varied from 3 days to 2 weeks.  The time requirement depends on the size of the application you are integrating.  It only took me 3 days to integrate Facebook Connect into a new site which did not have any existing users.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit difficult, yes, but it's not impossible. It shoud be about 2-5 days to study, understand, make tests and make it works (it also depends on how much you know of the facebook platfrm):

Here is a tuorial I wrote:

> http://www.barattalo.it/facebook-connect-tutorial/

it explains how to give the facebook login and how to post on users' wall.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in a Facebook connect or login button can be pretty easy now since there are some copy-and-paste solutions out there. If you're looking for a copy/paste solution that does some pretty simple members-only page protection, you can try this [Facebook Login tool](http://toolkit.launchbit.com). It's free and gives some basic analytics, I think.

Answer (score 0):

My point of view Facebook connect can be implemented by average programmer with in 2-3 hours If you aware about Facebook document and sound knowledge of API Key Secret.
Following documents that help for integrating Facebook into websites.

[Document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) use PHP for server-side programming and HTML/JavaScript for client-side code. These examples are very straightforward and easily translatable to other languages.

[Facebook Developer Tutorials.](http://facebook-developer.net/category/tutorials/)

[This article](http://devtacular.com/articles/bkonrad/how-to-integrate-with-facebook-connect/) shows few steps that describes how to integrate Facebook Connect into your
existing site.

Answer (score 0):

efpa is brilliant for this, its easy to use and saves you hours, it would take you less than 20 min, there is a really good youtube tutorial on this, they use efpa to create a web application, let users connect using their facebook accounts and then present them their home feed, from creating a facebook app to writing the code in 20 min;

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ri8io0bmKOc

btw efpa stand for (Easy Facebook PHP API), the library was written to make facebook intergration easy and usable by anyone. Check out their documentations page http://labs.gurron.com/projects.php?proj=efpa&pg=docs

Comment: Have you any connection to that product?

Comment: No I'm a web developer that makes websites for clients and I was told by a member on my web developers group on facebook about this about 3 days ago so I gave it a go, I think it would help BALA on this as it did me.